# Searchview Filters for more than one listfragment with custom adapter

Tags: android, filter, fragment, android-listfragment, searchview

I am using more than one listfragment activity in my project.

I struct in filtering the listview.

Is any possibility to add searchview to child fragment activity.?

How to handle this type of filteration???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by adding 
    **setHasOptionsMenu(true);**
code in all child fragment activity which extends listfragment.

setHasOptionsMenu(true); is to mention that child activity also has an menu options.